# Как получить параметры URL с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

В URL есть параметры:

- `clickid`
- `param1`
- `param2`

пример URL: `https://domain.com/index.php?clickid={clickid}&param1=22&param2=33`

Как я могу их извлечь и получить в таком виде: *clickid*:22:33?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51328250/1216425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ты уверен, что параметры будут добавлены именно в таком порядке, и других параметров не предвидится, можно пройтись по каждому параметру, собрать в массив и сджойнить его:

```js
const searchString = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

const params = [];

searchString.forEach((value) => {
  params.push(value);
});

const result = params.join(':');

console.log(result);
```

Можно просто достать каждое значение по ключу и собрать в строку:

```js
const searchString = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

const clickid = searchString.get('clickid');
const param1 = searchString.get('param1');
const param2 = searchString.get('param2');

const result = `${clickid}:${param1}:${param2}`; // clickid:22:23

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var params = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
var result = "";
for(i = 0; i < params.length; i ++) result += ":" + params[i].split("=")[1];
result = result.substring(1);
console.log(result);
```

Почитайте статью: [Передача и обработка данных в html-файле](https://www.spravkaweb.ru/javascript/sovet/get/)